# Why won't Scala optimize tail call with try/catch?

Tags: scala, try-catch, tail-recursion

In a [recent StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7931459/115478), I gave the following recursive code:

```scala
def retry[T](n: Int)(fn: => T): T = {
  try {
    fn
  } catch {
    case e if n > 1 =>
      retry(n - 1)(fn)
  }
}
```

If I add the `@tailrec` annotation, I get:

> Could not optimize @tailrec annotated method retry: it contains a
>   recursive call not in tail position.

I was able to hack a tail-recursive alternative, but I still wonder why this didn't optimize.  Why not?

Comment: If (n > 1) - really? Not n > 0 or n >= 1? And what happens if n == 1 (== 0)?

Comment: @user unknown - Obviously you pass in the number of tries total, not the number of retries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be tail-recursion optimized, this has to be transformed into something like the following:

```
def retry[T](n: Int)(fn: => T): T = {
  START:
    try {
      fn
    } catch {
      case e if n > 1 =>
        n = n - 1
        GOTO START
    }
}
```

When it executes the `GOTO` to loop, it has to leave to scope of the `catch` block. But in the original recursive version, the execution of the recursive call is still within the `catch` block. If the language allows that this could ever potentially change the meaning of the code, then this wouldn't be a valid optimization.

**EDIT:** From discussion with Rex Kerr in the comments, this is a behaviour-preserving transformation in Scala (but only when there is no `finally`). So apparently it's just that the Scala compiler doesn't yet recognise that the last call of a `catch` block where there is no `finally` is in a tail-call position.

Comment: Too much speculation, too much of which is wrong.  The bytecode is not the problem.  Bytecode doesn't even understand catch blocks, only a target for exceptions within a try block.  Specs for exception handling don't impact _this_ transformation; just try rewriting it as a while loop!

Comment: @Rex I'm happy to be corrected by someone who knows more about Java bytecode, but I did phrase it as a guess. I'm not sure I understand your last remark though. The tail-recursion transformation is about automatically rewriting code into something like a while loop, and the tail recursion taking place in a catch block clearly does inhibit the compiler from doing this. Either that's just a feature that hasn't been implemented, or the specs for exception handling **do** impact this transformation. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: It's a feature which has not been implemented.  There is no case where behavior would differ if you moved the jump outside of the catch block (as long as the logic was correct) in _this_ case.  The equivalent iterative code is `var i = n; while(true) { try { return(fn) } catch { case e if i>1 => i -= 1; } }`.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the list of implemented transformations for putting code in tail-recursive form include traversing exception-handling blocks.  These are particularly tricky, even though you can come up with examples (as you have) of where it ought to be legal.  (There are many cases that look legal which are not (e.g. if there is a `finally` block), or require considerably more complex winding/unwinding rules.)

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution elsewhere on SO. Basically, use a `return` with `fn` so that if `fn` returns w/o exception, so will your function. If `fn` does throw, and the exception meets the condition `n > 1`, then the exception is ignored and the recursive call happens after the catch block.

```
@tailrec
def retry[T](n: Int)(fn: => T): T = {
  try {
    return fn
  } catch {
    case e if n > 1 => // fall through to retry below
  }
  retry(n - 1)(fn)
}
```