# Scala tail recursion from finally block

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion, try-catch-finally

I want to apply a function `f` to each element of a `List` and not stop at the first error but throw the last error (if any) only:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def tryAll[A](xs: List[A])(f: A => Unit): Unit = {
  xs match {
    case x :: xt =>
      try {
        f(x)
      } finally {
        tryAll(xt)(f)
      }
    case _ =>
  }
}
```

But, the above code does not compile - it is complaining that this function is not tail recursive. Why not?

Comment: The function is not tail recursive since in the case an exception gets thrown, the `finally` block is not the last code to get executed.

Comment: @HristoIliev: I see - how can I write this in an efficient and idiomatic manner then?

Comment: I believe the idiomatic way would be to use `scala.util.Try` to wrap the function invocations, but I'm unable to provide you with a sample code.

Comment: You are not using properly @annotation.tailrec

Comment: Removing @annotation.tailrec code compiles

Comment: @mychemicalro: The point is not about removing the tailrec but understanding why this is not tail recursive. Also removing the annotation would cause StackOverflow for lists > 1M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution iterates over all elements and produces (throws) the last error if any:

```
def tryAll[A](xs: List[A])(f: A => Unit): Unit = {
  val res = xs.foldLeft(Option.empty[Throwable]) {
    case (maybeThrowable, a) =>
      Try(f(a)) match {
        case Success(_) => maybeThrowable
        case Failure(e) => Option(e)
      }
  }

  res.foreach(throwable => throw throwable)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @HristoIliev, your method cannot be tail recursive because the `finally` call is not guaranteed to be the tail call. This means that any method using `try` in this way will not be tail recursive. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8233456/2292812), also.

Calling the method again is a weird way of trying something repeatedly until it succeeds, because at each stage it's throwing an exception you are presumably not handling. Instead, I'd argue using a functional approach with `Try`, taking failures from a view until the operation succeeds. The only disadvantage to this approach is that it doesn't throw any exceptions for you to handle along the way (which can also be an advantage!).

```
def tryAll[A](xs: List[A])(f: A => Unit): Unit =
    xs.view.map(x => Try(f(x))).takeWhile(_.isFailure).force


scala> val list = List(0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0)

scala> tryAll(list)(a => println(10 / a))
2
```

If you really want to handle the exceptions (or just the last exception), you can change the return type of `tryAll` to `List[Try[Unit]]` (or simply `Try[Unit]` if you modify the code to only take the last one). It's better for the return type of the method to describe part of what it's actually doing--potentially returning errors.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure the intention of the method, but you can something like that:

```
  final def tryAll[A](xs: List[A])(f: A => Unit): Unit = {
      xs match {
        case x :: xt =>
          try {
            f(x)
          } catch {
            case e => tryAll(xt)(f)
          }
        case _ => //do something else
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this way to use @annotation.tailrec

From this:

```
def fac(n:Int):Int = if (n<=1) 1 else n*fac(n-1)
```

You should have this:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec 
def facIter(f:Int, n:Int):Int = if (n<2) f else facIter(n*f, n-1) 
def fac(n:Int) = facIter(1,n)
```

Comment: You have to accumulate values in f, so when you reach the base case, return it. It does not make sense for your method :/