# Scala Option Some/None idiom for functions that return Unit

Tags: scala, exception, error-handling

I have a number of function pairs to manipulate resource, for example:

```
def loadFile(name: String): Option[String]
def writeFile(name: String, data: String): ???
```

*loadFile* is currently implemented to return resultant String using Option Some/None but what about *writeFile*?

Like *loadFile*, if *writeFile* fails I would like it to return a response wrapped in a nice Try or Option rather than throw an exception or return a null, Boolean, or response code.

What are some recommended best practices?

```
def writeFile(name: String, data: String): Try(Unit)
```

or

```
def writeFile(name: String, data: String): Option(Unit)
```

and just test success flag?

What is the best scala-thonic way to approach this?

Comment: If you don't care about a result on success (other than it being successful), but do care about a result on error (exception), then I would definitely favor `Try[Unit]` over `Option[Unit]`.

Comment: don't forget about `Either`, either!

Comment: Option[Exception] will be my solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers here are pretty much the same as `Try[Unit]`, but require a little more boilerplate. This is about as simple as it gets (literally adding 3 letters to your function definition):

```
def writeFile(name: String, data: String): Try[Unit] = Try {
    // do write operation that may throw an exception
}
```

The huge advantage of `Try` is that it's a monad, so you're able to `map` and `flatMap` it (among other things) to compose multiple `Try` ops into a single one with ease. Say you need to do 3 of these operations together, and either return `Unit` or the first `Exception`.

```
val result: Try[Unit] = for {
    a <- writeFile(name1, data1)
    b <- writeFile(name2, data2)
    c <- writeFile(name3, data3)
} yield ()
```

You can match on the results:

```
result match {
    case Success(_) => println("Success!")
    case Failure(t) => println(s"Failure! {t.getMessage}")
}
```

You also have some other powerful combinator functions as seen in the [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.Try).

*And* you can also write a more generic method for retrying failures, as seen in the last block of code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7931459/2292812).

Answer (score 1):

I've gone with an approach that looks like this in the past.

```
trait Result
case object Success extends Result
case class Error(errorReason: String) extends Result

def writeFile(name: String): Result
```

It works pretty well with pattern matching paradigms.

```
def writeFileWithRetry(name: String)(numRetries: Int = 2): Result = {
  writeFile(name) match {
    case e: Error => 
      LOG.errorLog(s"Could not write $name: ${e.errorReason}")
      if (numRetries <= 0) e else writeFileWithRetry(name)(numRetries - 1)
    case r => r
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   def writeFile(name: String, data: String): Either[Exception, Unit] = try {
      doWrite(name, data)  
      Right(()) 
   } catch {
     case ex => Left(ex)
   }

    writeFile("foo", "bar") match {
       case Left(ex) => println("Failed with exception: " + ex)
       case _ => println("Success!")
    }
```