# Kafka producer: how to handle "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused"

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I use Kafka 0.10.1.0.

This is my producer:

```
val props: Properties = ...
val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, AnyRef](props)
val callback = new Callback {
   override def onCompletion(md: RecordMetadata, e: Exception): Unit = ...
}
producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, AnyRef]("topic", "hello"), callback)
```

But the above callback can't handle `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` in case when kafka-server is down.

**UPD**

The `ConnectionException` is raised in another thread (into `Sender` class which is used into `KafkaProducer`). Therefore we can't use `try {} catch` for it. Also I don't need retry mechanism, I need a way for handling this situation (for example, if Kafka is down and producer can't send message then I'm going to use some another Queue API).

Is there a way for handling this exception?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.  Scala provides a way to catch exceptions which takes the following form:

```
   try { 
   // ... 
   } 
   catch {
     case ioe: IOException => ... // more specific cases first !
     case e: Exception => ...
   }
```

So the most simple approach would be:

```
  try { 
     producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, AnyRef]("topic", "hello"), callback)
   } 
   catch {
     case ce: ConnectionException => // handle exception
   }
```

More complex but more robust would be a retry mechanism:

[What's the Scala way to implement a retry-able call like this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930814/whats-the-scala-way-to-implement-a-retry-able-call-like-this-one)

Also note that the Kafka Producer has a retry mechanism built into it,
which may also prove helpful:

> Setting a value greater than zero will
>   cause the client to resend any record whose send fails with a
>   potentially transient error. Note that this retry is no different than
>   if the client resent the record upon receiving the error. Allowing
>   retries without setting max.in.flight.requests.per.connection to 1
>   will potentially change the ordering of records because if two batches
>   are sent to a single partition, and the first fails and is retried but
>   the second succeeds, then the records in the second batch may appear
>   first.

Comment: Hi @crypto, thanks for the answer. But this way will not work because the `ConnectionException` is raised in another thread (into `Sender` class which is used into `KafkaProducer`). Therefore we can't use `try {} catch` for it.

Comment: yes, this is a separate thread, created inside `producer.send` method

Comment: So the exception is thrown before your callback is invoked?

Comment: When the exception throws, the callback is not invoked. And this exception appears in logs only. And we can't catch it.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000 happens before I get a ConnectionException.  I've tried an invalid host:port combination and the metadata fetch is timing out before i see any ConnectionException